# ERROR TypeError: session.run(...).subscribe is not a function Neo4j and Angular CLI

Tags: angular, neo4j

I'm trying display neo4j data into a graph inside my angular app.

I tried with Neovis.js, but nothing is getting displayed. Please help

Below is my code,

```
  import NeoVis from 'node_modules/neovis-ts/dist/neovis.js';

  ngOnInit() {
    this.draw();
  }

  draw() {
    const config = {
      container_id: 'viz',
      server_url: 'URL',
      server_user: 'neo4j',
      server_password: 'Password',
      initial_cypher: `MyQuery`
    };

    const viz = new NeoVis(config);
    viz.render();
  }
```

**Component.html**

```
<div id="viz"></div>
```

In Index.html,

```
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/neo4j-contrib/neovis.js/master/dist/neovis.js"></script>
```

I get this below error,

```
ERROR TypeError: session.run(...).subscribe is not a function
```

Please help. I'm stuck here

Note:- I can successfuly get the data from db and I can see the data in console.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like neovis-ts is a few commits behind the official repository that it has been forked from.  Do you get the same error if you use the original [neovis](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neovis.js) library rather than neovis-ts?

You could quickly try `window.NeoVis` as you've included it as a `<script>` tag.